# New versions of Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I was doing a bit research and I came across this comment.

> I have been working with Sencha products since Ext2. Throughout all
>   these years I have been rewriting my code numerous time just to adapt
>   to their freaking changing coding pattern.
>
> From the troublesome Class.superclass.method.call() to the new
>   me.callParent(), till the recent adoption of initialize & removal of
>   initComponent in ST2, I would suggest you to go for the newest release
>   since whatever in the past will not be reuse again. Learn the new
>   coding style, don't waste time on the old structure. It won't help you
>   much, considering our web is changing very fast and ST1 and ST2 is
>   pretty disjoint as well.
>
> While 1.1 is good old solid (much like Ext), v2 is much fun to work
>   with with the auto loader.

I'm ok with change, but I don't feel like revising my application every 6months or so.
My question is: how often does Sencha bring out a new version? (Can be EXTJS or Touch).
I did already try to find it on the website of Sencha but I think previous versions are banned to the dark ages or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a public road map available but like any software that is still growing, expect newer versions to be released. With the mobile space changing at a rapid pace, the Sencha team has to address those changes and meet the needs of their customers. It shouldn't be a deterrent from using Sencha products. In fact, with the release of ST2 and many adoptions from Ext JS4, they have not only simplified their path/direction but made it easier for us developers.

Comment: I should add... that if you are developing a mobile app, expect to be revising/updating/improving your app at least on an annual basis anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my main concern is that I have to do a major revise every time sencha updates. Additions to the framework is fine (new controls), new configuration options, but what sencha does (according to the post) is change the entire name of the function. This is troublesome for me (I think). I don't have a lot of experience revising sencha applications to a new version. Can you enlighten me a bit on this part?

Comment: I started with ST1 and migrated to ST2 when it hit RC. I had to refactor about 20%-30% of my code and wrap my head around the new differences. It wasn't easy but it wasn't a show stopper either. Software in its infancy should expect changes like the previous post, that's how it is improved. Now if they changed a method name in an incremental version of ST2.x I would be upset but I would expect some changes like that in a major release. HTML5 Mobile dev is the exception to the rule right now, get ready for new specs and standards, new devices and the unexpected.

Comment: Also, there are still plenty of devs on ST1. I still see a steady amount of questions here and on their forum. For whatever reason, they are still bound to efforts within the ST1 branch. You could always develop for ST2  and support it as long as it will continue to work on a device. You don't HAVE to update every time Sencha does. My 2 cents, its free and it's the best framework for a reason.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I think I just have to live with this.

Answer (score 0):

[A very quick google for ext js wiki.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_JS)

[A very quick google for sencha touch wiki.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sencha_Touch)